# what does animation means in scrollViewDidScroll?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In the doc, I found
scrollViewDidScroll:
If you scroll in code without animation, you will receive this message once.

scroll without animation and scroll with animation, what's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the view will scroll to that point with an animation (same as if you were using your finger), or it will jump to it directly.

For example, imagine that the user sees the top of the scroll, and you call scroll to the bottom with animation, the user will see all the scroll going down to the bottom, instead of just appearing there.